# I get a blank page after adding $block->getLayout()->createBlock() to the Module?

Tags: magento2, login, di, http-error-500

I am trying to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` into the `QuickOrder` module. I want the page to show a different message when the user is not logged in.

In the directory `app/code/Magento/QuickOrder/Block` i made the class `CheckLoggedIn.php`:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\QuickOrder\Block;

use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class CheckLoggedIn implements BlockInterface
{
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct( \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session)
    {
        $this->customerSession = $session;
    }

    public function isLoggedIn()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->isLoggedIn();
    }
}
```

and in `vendor\magento\module-quick-order\view\frontend\templates\widget\sku.phtml` , I added two lines of code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Order by SKU widget template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\QuickOrder\Block\Sku
 */
?>

// I added these two lines:
<?php $block2= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\QuickOrder\Block\CheckLoggedIn'); ?>
<h1>test: <?php $block2->isLoggedIn();?></h1>
```

but now when I refresh the page, I get a blank page with an `500 (Internal Server Error)`.
This is what I get in the `debug.log`:

`report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'multiple-wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []`

What am I doing wrong? Am I trying to inject the module in a wong way?

thanks

UPDATE:
The problem is the first line of the code. If I comment it, then I get the error `undefined variable $block2`. So the internal server error emerges from the frist line. And btw, the other pages work, only the corresponding url `/quick-order` is blank.

Comment: I bet you will find a php Fatal error in your web server logs. Look for it & paste it

Comment: I do not see anything in `/var/log` files. All I see is the `Broken reference`  thing that I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy static content and check your .htaccess files from root directory and pub/static..

Comment: what do you mean  "check your .htaccess files from root directory and pub/static"?

Comment: Of course I am deploying the static content each time

Answer (score 0):

Must be Error in code

Please do view source of page via ctrl+u and check Error will there in Red Color